# Cutting text from an image

Tags: text

I am designing a poster for a local band and they sent me a picture of a previous poster so that I could use it for the text. Is there a way I can simply cut "Rumours" out and use it for my poster?
[image]

Comment: Hey Sadie and welcome! What have you tried? What relevant programs do you have access to? Would using the same font be acceptable (preferable?)  to cutting out that part of the image?

Comment: I have tried using Adobe illustrator and photoshop. The best luck I've had was using the pen tool to cut out each letter but this is not entirely accurate. Unfortunately, it's not really a font because it was created by a different designer.

Comment: Are you needing to change the size? The color? Or just copy it exactly?

Comment: IMHO you should look for a similar font, create `RUMOURS`, and then edit the path to add the arc between the first R and the O. The original (1977) predates Photoshop and Illustrator, but the designer likely use [Letraset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letraset) letters and added the arc.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think I would put the image into Photoshop, use the magic wand to remove the cream color, then take the now free letters and put them into Illustrator. Then use live trace to vectorize them. Hope this helps!

[image: Using the magic want to select and delete the cream background]

[image: Live Trace the artifact laden letters in Illustrator and voila!]

Comment: @SadieThrift The proper way to thank is click an upvote. And if the answer happens to be the perfect one, then click the answer to be accepted as the best.